# Which application to replace Superputty / PuTTY CM in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, software-recommendation, ssh

Is there any application in macOS (MacBook Pro) which can work like SuperPuTTY / PuTTY CM does in Windows? I am looking for a free one.

What I need is to organize my ssh sessions. I can ssh to my machines using terminal but they are individual windows and kind of hard to get IP addresses / names every time I need to connect to them.

It can also be an application which uses terminal application in Mac for ssh ..

Answer (score 2):

Look further into terminal before you give up on it. Under the **Shell** menu, you'll find **New Remote Connection...**. The list of default servers will be auto-populated via Bonjour, but you can still create and save new sessions for ssh, sftp, ftp, and telnet. Of course, the default services in UNIX also allow you to create your SSH keys so that when you log into a remote host, you don't have to enter your password.

You can also customize your windows with a lot of features not seen in simple Windows packages like PuTTY. Be sure to check out your Terminal > Preferences... for customizing colors, keyboards, shell commands, fonts, screen size, key mappings, terminal emulation, and a whole lot more.

Oh, you can also create new sessions in tabs, not just new windows; the second option under the **Shell** menu will do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the tab features, terminal has an imbedded menu for it under Windows > merge all windows.  Although keep alives are not included in Terminal...